# Php write data on div from database

Tags: php, html, mysql, css, while-loop

I have a project I need to create a FlipPage website that takes posts from mysql database. So I thikned that I can do it with while function on PHP.

So firs of all I have created a database with 2 tables. 'pages' and 'posts'.

'pages' table structure

[image]

'posts' table structure

[image]

After I wrote this code. It takes all data from tables and writes it. I have problem with while function. Im using FLipPageLayout design. Pages are separated by div tag. When Im writing this code page shows me all posts at the same page. But I need to allocate posts to pages. When Im writing  in while loop it creates new pages for every post. But in table I created pageid row. How to use that row to organize posts on every page.

```
        if ($pagerow['flipcontent'] == 1) {
            $box = 'w-50 h-100';
        }
        if ($pagerow['flipcontent'] == 2) {

            $box = 'w-25 h-100';
        }

        echo '<div class="f-page">';

        while($postrow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($postquery)) {
            echo '<div class="f-title">';
            echo '<h2>' . $pagerow['title'] . '</h2>';
            echo '</div>';
            echo '<div class="box ' . $box . '">';
            echo '<div class="img-cont"><img src="' . $postrow['photo'] . '"></div>';
            echo '<h3>' . $postrow['title'] . ' <span>' . $postrow['date'] . '</span></h3>';
            echo '<p>' . $postrow['content'] . '</p>';
            echo '</div>';
        } //End of while
        echo '</div>';
```

Comment: Emre, may i know if you want to load the page for next page or you want to use ajax for that purpose or you want to show and hide contents on solely front-end?

Comment: Thanks for your feedback Shudhansh, I think that first option gonna be better. Becouse if I will load so much data in page it can slow down traffic. But If it will load on page rotation it gonna be more economical. Also sorry for my bad Endlish I hope you understand me :( .

Comment: means page url may include different page id?

Comment: Yes it can include different id. In facts it doesn't matter for me.. I tried to do while with get variable but it didn't worked. It workes only when you're refreshing page. I just need to get work this while loop correctly for every page with maximum traffic economy.

Comment: so you want to load the different page with different id without even reload?......

Comment: Ok. So emre, you may not use first option. You have to either use ajax or you'll have to make your website a single page application with jquery or angular.

Comment: How can I do it with ajax. Can you help me or just provide some information to google it :)

Comment: i can show you a code snippet in answer. All you have to do is nothing but bind the click event to fetch data from server with the same SQL code you have used so far and get the return result.  By the way if you have limited pages, it is preferable to load all pages in different divs   on a single page and only show the div, specific to a button click. It would be easy and maintainable for you. .What would you prefer?.....i may tell you any technique.

Comment: Pages are gonna be unlimited. Admin will be able to add as many pages as he wants.

Comment: ok so i'm going to tell you how to use ajax.

Comment: Ok Im waitin for answer thanks very much :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope you have include jquery library. If not, then paste 
`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>` 
in your meta tag.

Since, you have index page. So find the relative path of your SQL query file and note that. 
in SQL query file, after the database query, add this:

```
if ($pagerow['flipcontent'] == 1) {
        $box = 'w-50 h-100';
    }
    if ($pagerow['flipcontent'] == 2) {

        $box = 'w-25 h-100';
    }

    echo '<div class="f-page">';

    while($postrow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($postquery)) {
        echo '<div class="f-title">';
        echo '<h2>' . $pagerow['title'] . '</h2>';
        echo '</div>';
        echo '<div class="box ' . $box . '">';
        echo '<div class="img-cont"><img src="' . $postrow['photo'] . '"></div>';
        echo '<h3>' . $postrow['title'] . ' <span>' . $postrow['date'] . '</span></h3>';
        echo '<p>' . $postrow['content'] . '</p>';
        echo '</div>';
    } //End of while
    echo '</div>';
```

mow create a js file or script tag and add this:
( if your SQL file path is a variable 'path' and the next page or x-page button is #page-x and the wrapper for your all pages is same #f-main)

```
    $('#page-x').click(function(){
    $.get(path, function(data){
        //console.log(data); //if you will remove '//' before console, you may see the fetched data in console. But use only for test neither. remove it.
        $('#main').html(data);
    });    
});
```

that's it . 
If your code not get the jquery, you may include the cdn tag in SQL CODE page in bottom.
For more details you may learn at [w3school](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_intro.asp)

Comment: if you have still problem i'll solve tomorrow. Now i/m going for sleep. Good night.

Comment: It didn't worked for me becouse  not sure that there is any button. Can you check the design and answer then? http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/05/07/experimental-page-layout-inspired-by-flipboard/ .

Comment: Thanks for showing your design reference. Because now i got to know, what you are trying to achieve. Actually you are trying to achieve the third option, that i told you before. You need a SPA, say Single Page Apllication, That loads all pages and show the different page according to the click. Be aware, It is not ajax . It is just showing and hiding different divs on different click.

Comment: but i'm little surprised, if you are asking for help. Everything is explained there. Even you have the source code.

Comment: You have to do nothing for server side.  It is front-end application. Just Precisely follow the procedures given there.